# How to secure database credentials in spring mvc service layer

Tags: spring-mvc, security, credentials, database-security, key-management

I have to create a banking application using `Spring MVC` and `MySQL` enterprise database. Encryption and Decryption of data are done using keys provided by MySQL Enterprise database. Some of the options that I have found to secure this database credentials are:

1. Storing credentials in key store - but I want keys to be stored out of service code
2. Using Azure key store or Azure App Settings - but I am looking for a free source
3. Using Hashing - Still, the keys are inside service code
4. Using self-signed certificates - Again these certificates have to be deployed, which may be insecure

Now how can I store this database credentials out of service code?

Answer (score 1):

A common and difficult problem, I recommend https://www.vaultproject.io/ by Hashicorp.

Comment: I have implemented it by storing private info in localhost, how can I use the same when the service is deployed?